# Javascript: querySelector only selects 1 div. How do I get it to select all divs with the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using `document.querySelector` and I need it to select all divs that contains the class "test". So far querySelector selects the first div only.

How do I do that with my current JavaScript?

```js
var removeCurveStroke = document.querySelector('.test');

if(removeCurveStroke.classList.contains('card-decorator-stroke')){
    removeCurveStroke.classList.remove("card-decorator-stroke");
    removeCurveStroke.classList.add("brand-curve-stroke");
}
```

Any help is gladly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll('.test');`
[Documetnation for querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.card-decorator-stroke').forEach(function(removeCurveStroke) {
   removeCurveStroke.classList.remove("card-decorator-stroke");
   removeCurveStroke.classList.add("brand-curve-stroke");
});
```

```css
.test{
 height: 1rem;
 background: blue;
}
.card-decorator-stroke {
  background: red;
}
.brand-curve-stroke {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test card-decorator-stroke"></div>
```

Comment: when I do that I get an error that say "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')" so I'm stuck.

Comment: Your question has been answered. You are stuck on a new problem. Now you have a collection of elements, not one element. You can't call `.remove` directly on an array, you have to iterate the elements, for instance with a `for...of` loop.

Comment: How do I write that correctly to work in a for loop?

Comment: You could read the documentation :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#accessing_the_matches

Comment: Thank you sir. In ES5 how would I write that? We have Grunt running and I'm getting an error that says "for of' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz)."

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

not recommendable but try `document.getElementsByClassName("test")`

Comment: Why not recommendable?

Answer (score -1):

You can try with jquery

```
$(".test .card-decorator-stroke").addClass("brand-curve-stroke").removeClass("card-decorator-stroke");
```